# GraphQL pubsub in a different node pm2 process

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, pm2

I have a graphql subscription and a cronjob running a scraper every minute. I want to split the scraper into its own process and continously run both using PM2. Currently I can access pubsub context/variable in my scraper to send out pubsub alerts

ie:

```
import {pubsub} from "../../src/index.js"
```

If i split the scraper into its own process though, how can I access the pubsub context and or publish to the same server/websocket as the other subscriptions?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks